# C# Interfaces with generics and reflection - How to get the intellisense to work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, generics, reflection

my code (bellow) is working... however, at the moment the solution does not provide me intellisense for the methods that the object `rs` allows.

How am I able to either "cast" my dynamic object to the type of the interface (`typeInterface`) ? or use `as` when I call `CreateInstance`?

```
public interface IReportService<T, K>
{
    Task<GetReportDataAnswer<T>> GetReportData(GenerateReportRequest request);
    Task<GetReportAnswer<K>> GetReport(T data);
}

public class Dummy1Service : BaseReportService, IReportService<Dummy1Data, Dummy1Report>
{
    public Dummy1Service(TTAction action) : base(action)
    {
    }
    //.... implementation of the methods GetReport and GetReportData
}

...
var reflectionData = string.Format("Reports.Elements.Dummy1.Dummy1Data");
var reflectionReport = string.Format("Reports.Elements.Dummy1.Dummy1Report");
var reflectionService = string.Format("Reports.Elements.Dummy1.Dummy1Service");

Type typeData = Type.GetType(reflectionData);
Type typeReport = Type.GetType(reflectionReport);
Type typeService = Type.GetType(reflectionService);

/***************************************************************************/
//ConstructorInfo c = typeService.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { }, null);

 var typeInterface = typeof(IReportService<,>).MakeGenericType(typeData, typeReport);

 dynamic rs = Activator.CreateInstance(typeService, TTAction);

 var data = await rs.GetReportData(request); //NOTE: this is the part without intellisense 
 /***************************************************************************/
```

Comment: What autocompletions do you want? The compiler does not know the type of `rs` at all.

Comment: @Sweeper the type of "rs" is the value of "typeInterface" (at least in theory)

Comment: But the compiler does not know the value of `typeInterface`, does it? What methods would intellisense show?

Comment: @Sweeper the RS should be of type IReportService where the T, K are the types that theDummy1Service receives (Dummy1Data, Dummy1Report): Therefor, the intellisense should show me: GetReportData and GetReport

Comment: Can you cast it to `IReportService<Dummy1Data, Dummy1Report>`?

Comment: @shingo nop :-D... the types will only be known by "namespace.class" string values.

Comment: So intellisense wouldn't know either.

Comment: @shingo, the intellisense SHOULD know the base Interface and the 2 methods that it is offering: GetReportData and GetReport... at least that is what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: The intellisense also needs to know T and K in order to work. You need to define a non-generic base interface.

Comment: @shingo at the moment, I think I will leave the code the way it is, since it is working (plus  failsafe logic)..... and just write some comments saying: "If you need to know the methods/parameters of that object, look at the specification of the Interface X.

Comment: It's impossible, because the ocmpiler needs to know what T or K is to be able to resolve the interface. The only way is to create a non-generic base interface, so you have `public interface IReportService<T, K> : IBaseReportService` but then you couldn't access any of the functions that refer to T or K. I guess the questionis: what are you *doing* with `data` after this code?

Comment: `resharper` tries to help provide completions in this situation but any suggestions are inherently unreliable reflecting a best guess.

Answer (score 1):

For the IntelliSense to work you need to provide static type information for the Code Analysis Tool (IntelliSense) or the compiler. For simplification I use the term compiler in the following.

As you already noticed this is impossible with the `dynamic` type as it has no static type information. From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/interop/using-type-dynamic

> The `dynamic` type is a static type, but an object of type `dynamic` bypasses static type checking

In other words it signals the compiler that you know what you are doing and that the compiler does not have to worry about what is going on with this object. So IntelliSense can't help you.

For using IntelliSense the compiler what the object can be. I don't have a full grasp of what your situation is but generally I understood that you need to build some instance of `IReportService<T, K>` without knowing (at the writing of the code) which type the instance should really have.

I think there are three approaches to this. I don't think there are more but I also don't no everything:

1. Using `dynamic` and guaranteeing the compiler that you are knowing what you are doing.

This is the current situation and you don't like it so it's probably not an option.

This has only to be the option if you **want** to generate and use objects which are not of the given interface.

Then there are either two possibilities. Either the calling assembly (where the Interface is created / instantiated) has compile-time access to the assembly in which the class (which implements the interface) is defined or it has no access to it. If it has then you can solve this problem either by option 2 or 3. If it doesn't that you have to use option 3.

2. Using a generic factory method.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics

> Generics introduces the concept of type parameters to .NET, **which make it possible to design classes and methods that defer the specification of one or more types until the class or method is declared and instantiated by client code**.

As stated in the quote, generics are used to defer the specification of what exact object you want. Our goal is to defer the explicit mention of the concrete type to the point in which we know which concrete type we want.

The goal is to give the method which creates the service, the information of the type not via strings but rather type parameters.

```cs
IReportService<TData, TReport> CreateReportService<TService, TData, TReport>(TTAction action)
    where TService : IReportService<TData, TReport>
{
    // Cast is safe here
    return (IReportService<TData, TReport>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TService), action);
}
```

This has the downside that you are stating explicitly that all types of `TService` have a constructor which takes a `TTAction` as a parameter. Also this would cascade the use of generics upwards until the point we know which one to use.

To use this code you would have to call it like following

```cs
var rs = CreateReportService<Dummy1Service, Dummy1Data, Dummy1Report>();
var data = await rs.GetReportData(request);
```

3. Using a factory and dependency injection

There are situation in which we might never now which concrete type our services is. In those situation it best (imo) to force the caller / client of our service to provide a ways of instantiating his service. We can do this by providing an interface which creates a concrete type of our interface.

```cs
public interface IReportServiceFactory<TData, TReport>
{
    // if TTAction is only specifc to Dummy1Service
    IReportService<TData, TReport> CreateService();
    // else
    IReportService<TData, TReport> CreateService(TTAction action);
}
```

**Note:** if `TTAction` is specifc for `Dummy1Service` and unique for each instance of the service, the method above don't work and some more thought has to be put in how to solve this problem smarter.

Then for each implementation of the service, create a factory which creates the service **not** via reflection but with the right constructor.

In your main logic then inject the factory and call the method to create the service.

```cs
// Inject the factory, for example in the constructor
IReportServiceFactory<TData, TReport> _factory = ...;
// Use the factory
var rs = _factory.CreateService();
var data = await rs.GetReportData(request);
```